# Routing wifi from a router to another router for my iPad

Tags: routing

I have a Linksys router at my desktop for wifi, but want to route the wifi to a camper close to the house. Can I route the wifi to my Linksys smart router without hooking up any cables to my computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need a repeater (either another router that supports a "Bridge" or "Repeater" function).

Basically, it would need to be close enough to Router1 to get signal and it would repeat the signal extending the range.  If setup right, it would still use the same SSID as Router1 and password.

Whether or not your "linksys smart router" supports that depends on which model you have.

Comment: And be aware that your effective bandwidth will be approximately halved!

Comment: to my understanding the ip aress of the second rotor has to be in range of the first rotor? This is my first time doing this so it's very new to me.

Comment: I believe the same Sub-Net, yes.  So most home routers by default are `192.168.1.x`, where X is the identifier on the local level.  So, router1 could be .1 and router2 .2 or whatever.

Comment: @Nicole If you've properly set up router2 as a bridge, you should not need to set the IP, as it will get assigned one from router1.

Comment: my rotor is a Linksys smart wifi rotor N600 network manager EA 2700.. with a smart rotor will it cut the network in half still? or bandwidth I mean.

Comment: it is also 4 gigabit port

Comment: oh and I forgot to add that the wifi rotor to the desk top is off routing off Hugh's net.. I can still use this other router as a bridge right?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help so far, it's very helpful.

Comment: Nicole, it is frowned upon to have lengthy discussions in comments.  Also, people (outside of the "answerer") do not see your replies unless you "@" them.  So please try to consolidate.  Some reviewers say with a firmware update, it does support repeating.  However, I didn't see official stuff saying so.  Please remember to accept the answer if it satisfies your question (in your view, should be a check mark near the answer).